# How to delete all containers and images in containerd?

Tags: docker, containerd

I only have containerd installed, I'm using it for my k8s container runtime. I'm trying to clean up things. What might be the equivalent of the ff docker commands in containerd:

```
sudo docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)
sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To delete images:

```
ctr -n k8s.io i rm $(ctr -n k8s.io i ls -q | grep your_filter)
```

The arguments mean:

- `-n`: namespace
- `i`: image
- `ls`: list
- `-q`: show only ref

A similar command works for containers:

```
ctr -n k8s.io c rm $(ctr -n k8s.io c ls -q | grep your_filter)
```

Comment: And if you are using microk8s, the `containerd` CLI command is `microk8s.ctr`